# Calculating $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos x\sin x-x}{\sin^3 x}$ using taylor series

Tags: calculus, limits, taylor-expansion

I am given the following limit, and need to calculate it using taylor series:

$$\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos{x}\sin{x}-x}{\sin^3{x}}$$

$$\sin{x}=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}...$$

$$\cos{x}=1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}...$$

The problem I'm facing is how many terms to take when plugging in each taylor series into the original limit. I read in another thread that the lowest exponent in the denominator that I'll get is $x^3$, which means the largest degree I should have in the numerator is also $x^3$. Doing this I get:

$$\frac{\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\left(x\right)-x}{x^3+...}= \frac{\frac{x^3}{2}}{x^3+...}$$

Of course I get the limit is $-\frac12$ which is incorrect. What did I do wrong?

Please, I'd prefer hints and a correction rather than a full blown answer.

Comment: If you go up to the order $3$ in the denominator you need to go up to the order $3$ for each term in the numerator.

Comment: In particular: do not omit the $-x^3/3!$ term of the sine series.

Comment: Also consider using the O-notation.

Comment: @MrYouMath What example is the meaning of the O notation? Does it mean +further terms?

Comment: @Jennifer This is exactly what I needed to be able to solve it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not expand each element up to the same order in their Taylor series :
$$\cos (x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+o(x^3)$$
$$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+o(x^3)$$
$$(\sin(x))^3=x^3+o(x^3)$$

Now we have : $$\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{(\cos x)(\sin x)-x}{(\sin x)^3}=\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x-\frac{x^3}{3!}-\frac{x^3}{2!}-x+o(x^3)}{x^3+o(x^3)}=\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{-\frac{2x^3}{3}+o(x^3)}{x^3+o(x^3)}=\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{-2x^3}{3x^3}=-\frac{2}{3}$$

Comment: I'm trying to use taylor series to solve another similar limits question. How do I know how many terms to take in the denominator? i.e. lets say in the denominator I have sinxcosx

Comment: Well you need to take in the denominator the terms up to $x^n$ where $n$ is the order of your Taylor expansion in the numerator.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$\cos x\sin x-x=\dfrac{\sin2x-2x}2$$

Now use the expansion of $\sin2x$ and $$\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\sin h}h=1$$

Comment: This says absolutely nothing about the OP's question, which was "where's the error?"

Comment: Not an answer to the question, which is: "what did I do wrong?"  Of course there are other ways to do the problem, but Ronald wants to do it using Taylor series.

Comment: Although you don't exactly focus on the error committed by OP (there is another beautiful answer which does that) your approach is best because here we don't need to do multiplication or division of Taylor series. +1 In general I have found that it is better to apply some transformation on the expression before expanding into Taylor series. This many times avoid multiplication, division (or even inversion) of series.